# Using a Python DataFrame to Aggregate All Records Which Match on One Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of 2 columns, 'id' and 'recordhash' that I am using to compare records. I can get a list of records that match on 'recordhash' using:

`dups = df[df['recordhash'].duplicated(keep=False).sort_values('recordhash')`

but they output as:

```
id      recordhash
------------------
1        ab15
10       ab15
```

I would like to display them as:

```
matching   recordhash
---------------------
1, 10       ab15
```

This seems like it would be pretty straightforward but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grouped = df.groupby('recordhash')['id'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x))).reset_index()        
grouped.rename(columns={'id': 'matching'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Perfect! That does exactly what I need. Thanks.